# memory-mapping in python using numpy error

Tags: python, numpy, memory-mapping

```
OUT_DIR = '/media/sf_3dAnalysis/simMatrix/'  
SIM_FILE = 'similarity.npy'

data = np.lib.format.open_memmap(OUT_DIR+SIM_FILE, mode='w+', dtype='float32', shape=(len(filelist),len(filelist)))
del data
```

So I get the following error message when running this code...
`mmap.error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`. I really don't understand what I am doing wrong. I am running this in a Linux VM if that's relevant. Also, what's particularly curious is the matrix is created after the code runs, but it still crashes saying the argument is invalid which makes no sense as to why it would be creating the matrix when it says the argument is invalid.

Is there anything special I need to do to get memory mapping to work on a linux machine versus windows and mac? Because it is working fine on my mac and windows machine. I guess I should specify even more, is there some setting or something that needs to be set-up in a virtual machine to have memory mapping working? Because I tried it on a computer running Linux normally, and it worked.

Comment: How big is the file? Did you create it in the VM or import it? What is the spec of the VM?

Comment: The file is about 60 GB, and it is created in the Virtual Manager. And I don't know what you mean by the spec of the VM?

Comment: woops that was a typo. Sorry. And the exact shape is the length of a file list which I didn't think was particularly relevant. But I guess it might be. shape = (len(filelist), len(filelist)) is the exact statement.

Comment: Sorry and I should note the len(filelist) is 120821

Comment: OK, `shape=(120821, 120821)` will create a 60GB matrix/file.

Comment: Spec of the VM: 32 vs 64 bit? Memory allocated? Noumber of CPUs etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed my problem guys. I created a local copy of the matrix on the Virtual Machine. I then moved that copy to a shared folder. Here is the code illustrating that.

```
#create local copy
data = np.memmap(SIM_FILE, dtype='float32', mode='w+', 
          shape=(len(filelist),len(filelist)))
#move local copy to shared folder
os.system('mv' + " ~/Desktop/" + SIM_FILE + " " + OUT_DIR )
```

Comment: I see you switched from `np.lib.format.open_memmap` to `np.memmap` as in my suggestion. Isn't this the reason for your code working? I don't see how `os.system('mv'...` can solve your problem... Unless the failing stamen was not the first one but the second.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to replicate your error with the example given above.

`mmap.error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` is the error code from the low-level call to the libc `mmap` routine see http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory_002dmapped-I_002fO.html

> mmap returns the address of the new mapping, or -1 for an error.
>
> Possible errors include:
>
> EINVAL Either address was unusable, or inconsistent flags were given.

I guess it's <strike>an out of memory condition</strike> because you are trying to allocate a too large block, that does not fit into the VM virtual memory space.

Comment: What does out of memory mean? Like the hard drive ran out of memory? Or the computer ran out of virtual memory?

Comment: Also what can I do to fix it?

Comment: So I should allocate to the VM more virtual memory space?

Comment: How to fix: do you really need a 120000x120000 float32 matrix? It's a huge data structure... If possible I would try splitting the access to smaller chunks of this matrix, and abandon the idea of using the `.npy` format. It is more flexible, but maybe it's not well suited for such big matrices. Use `np.memmap` directly, with `offset != 0` for accessing portions of the file.

Comment: And yes, of course a VM with a 64 bit kernel is necessary to address 60GB of data (or 32 bit with LFS). Note however that physical memory + swap can be less than 60GB, "since mmapped pages can be stored back to their file when physical memory is low".

Comment: So I don't think the problem is with my VM's memory or anything because I tried creating a mmap matrix of shape=(100,100) and that wouldn't work either. Well it works in the sense that it creates the matrix, but then crashes.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot replicate your problem: you should publish your full stack trace with version information (numpy, kernel, glibc) and hope that some can one replicate the bug. Does `data = np.memmap(filename, dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(100,100))` works?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got the same error when trying to access the memmap again in mode='w+' when it was still open in the python instance. Only resetting the kernel helped