# Save big matrix to a file with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I needed to create a numpy matrix with the following code

```
encoder_data = np.zeros((347101, 400, 347101), dtype='float32')
```

but when i execute that code it issues MemoryError so im thinking if i could the matrix into file would also be good.

So i came across on [this answer that uses memmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149803/working-with-big-data-in-python-and-numpy-not-enough-ram-how-to-save-partial-r?answertab=active#tab-top) to save the matrix to a file and i came up with the following code

```
encoder_input_data = np.memmap('encoder_input_data.memmap', dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(347101, 400, 347101))
```

but with the above code it issues another error "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument"

Can someone help me save the same results of `np.zeros((347101, 400, 347101), dtype='float32')` to a file? Im new to python so i don't exactly know what to do now.

Comment: Do you really want an array this large? This is going to create a massive file that you may not be able to store. Your error may be related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/17663651/6942527.

Comment: Yes i really need it.

Comment: i dont know what your use case is but since its all zeros can you use sparse arrays from scipy?

Comment: Well, you could look into [`np.save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html), which has the option of using pickling. I think that could help with compressing your data a bit. But sparse arrays are probably the way to go here.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378): You ask how to create a huge file (175 Terabyte) but maybe the question should be how to avoid such an unwieldy data structure in the task you are solving. (If you are on 32 bit Python this blows the available address space; Don't know how 64 bit Python would take it...)

Comment: @kazemakase you are right :) Basically i was trying to map audio to an image and since one audio is 400D and an image feature is 40D. So i was using https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_seq2seq.py so i tried to treat 400d as the english characters and 40D as the french characters but it looks like i cant go this way. :(

I was in the part of creating matrix for encoder_input_data and run into error :D